# Place Holder Text In Textbox Should be hide when clicked in C#.net

Tags: javascript, .net, c#-4.0

I want to know How to use placeholders in textbox. I want to Use Some text box which Must Say "Enter Your Name Here".. And I want to clear the text When the user click the text box. if he does'nt enter anything in the Textbox Again It should say "Enter Your Name Here".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Receiver name" maxlength="40" id="fname" name="fname" class="ci-heading ci-shadow-inset ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
```

In Asp.net you can write it as:

```
<ASP:TextBox id="txt1" placeholder="Receiver name"></ASP:TextBox>
```

Simple html code :

```
<html>
<body>  
<form action="#" method="POST">  
    <input type="text" placeholder="Receiver name" maxlength="40" id="fname" name="fname" class="ci-heading ci-shadow-inset ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        </form>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```